# Best practice when changing browser back behavior?

Tags: javascript, browser, back-button

I am building a vocabulary drill educational training and test application using node js.

The first page is a start page with some "welcome" information. Next, there is a series of training pages shows a vocabulary item (one item per page). After 10 page, the client is taken to a test page where they get quizzed.

It is easy to "cheat" by simply going back and reviewing the lessons.

What are good ways to prevent going back? Is disabling the back button a good approach? Is there an approach where the back button goes all the way back to the start page? i.e redirect the browsers back button to my "start page"?

Comment: Well you can not disable the back button.... but you can record that they were on the page and forward them to the correct location.

Comment: It's also easy to take screenshots of each page or open the test in a new tab.  There's ultimately no way to prevent "cheating" in a browser.  If you sent the client information, there is no way to control what happens to that information.

Comment: @PaulAbbott yes that is true, but I want to do as much as reasonably possible to prevent/deter cheating.